# Expand a postgres array of JSON within a single column into multiple records

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table called `goals` where each row contains 1 goal.  The data about specific metrics for the goal is stored in ARRAY of JSON called `goal_metrics`. Sometimes there is 1 metric, sometimes there are 0 metrics, other times there are multiple metrics.  I want to extract all of the goal metrics into a new table, with 1 line per metrics and the original goal_id that metric belongs to.

This is what `table1` looks like currently:

```
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| goal_id | goal_owner | goal_create_at |                                                                                                                                                                                                             goal_metrics                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   69660 |     148191 |     1566576355 | [{'metric_owner': '148191', 'metric_create_at': '1566576374', 'metric_target': '10'}, {'metric_owner': '148191', 'metric_create_at': '1566576403', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '148191', 'metric_create_at': '1566576428', 'metric_target': '3'}, {'metric_owner': '148191', 'metric_create_at': '1566576450', 'metric_target': '3'}]                                                                                    |
|   68443 |     146270 |     1565911160 | [{'metric_owner': '144534', 'metric_create_at': '1565911175', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '144352', 'metric_create_at': '1565911191', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '144352', 'metric_create_at': '1565911212', 'metric_target': '15'}, {'metric_owner': '146270', 'metric_create_at': '1565911353', 'metric_target': '23'}]                                                                                   |
|   68440 |     146270 |     1565910356 | [{'metric_owner': '144061', 'metric_create_at': '1565910380', 'metric_target': '3'}, {'metric_owner': '144061', 'metric_create_at': '1565910462', 'metric_target': '0'}, {'metric_owner': '144534', 'metric_create_at': '1565910523', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '143866', 'metric_create_at': '1565911422', 'metric_target': '6'}]                                                                                     |
|   68442 |     146270 |     1565910746 | [{'metric_owner': '143866', 'metric_create_at': '1565910863', 'metric_target': '9'}, {'metric_owner': '143866', 'metric_create_at': '1565910881', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '144534', 'metric_create_at': '1565910905', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '146270', 'metric_create_at': '1565910927', 'metric_target': '1'}, {'metric_owner': '144534', 'metric_create_at': '1565910956', 'metric_target': '1'}] |
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this is what I'm trying to get to:

```
+--------------+------------------+---------------+---------+
| metric_owner | metric_create_at | metric_target | goal_id |
+--------------+------------------+---------------+---------+
|       143321 |       1557774894 |            56 |   53513 |
|       143321 |       1557774933 |           100 |   53513 |
|       143321 |       1557774983 |            10 |   53513 |
|       143321 |       1557775102 |           100 |   53513 |
|       143321 |       1557775388 |           100 |   53513 |
|       148191 |       1566576374 |            10 |   69660 |
|       148191 |       1566576403 |             1 |   69660 |
|       148191 |       1566576428 |             3 |   69660 |
|       148191 |       1566576450 |             3 |   69660 |
|       144534 |       1565911175 |             1 |   68443 |
|       144352 |       1565911191 |             1 |   68443 |
|       144352 |       1565911212 |            15 |   68443 |
|       146270 |       1565911353 |            23 |   68443 |
|       144061 |       1565910380 |             3 |   68440 |
|       144061 |       1565910462 |             0 |   68440 |
|       144534 |       1565910523 |             1 |   68440 |
|       143866 |       1565911422 |             6 |   68440 |
|       143866 |       1565910863 |             9 |   68442 |
|       143866 |       1565910881 |             1 |   68442 |
|       144534 |       1565910905 |             1 |   68442 |
|       146270 |       1565910927 |             1 |   68442 |
|       144534 |       1565910956 |             1 |   68442 |
+--------------+------------------+---------------+---------+
```

If it was just a regular JSON column, I could use `SELECT goal_metric -> 'metrics_owner' AS metrics_owner`, but because it's an ARRAY of variable length, that won't work.  I think that I need to use `JSON_TO_RECORDSET`, and I've been experimenting with that, but I haven't been able to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: You want `jsonb_array_elements`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different possible ways ([Postgres JSON documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=39cd60ab95ad2c3658396e973d7abb80)

---

**A:** Using `json_array_elements()`

```
SELECT
    goal_id,
    (elems ->> 'metric_owner')::int AS metric_owner,
    (elems ->> 'metric_create_at')::int AS metric_create_at,
    (elems ->> 'metric_target')::int AS metric_target
FROM
    table1,
    json_array_elements(goal_metrics) as elems
```

This expands every array element into one row. These expanded JSON objects can be queried for their attributes. This gives out `text` types. If you want them to be `int` types, you need a cast.

---

**B:** Using `json_to_recordset()`

```
SELECT
    goal_id,
    elems.*
FROM
    table1,
    json_to_recordset(goal_metrics) 
        AS elems(metric_owner int, metric_create_at int,metric_target int)
```

This does the same as in (A) in one step. You just need to define the output types.

---

**C:** If you have to do this operation regularly, it might be useful to define the output type once. Then you can use it within `json_populate_recordset()`:

```
CREATE TYPE metrics_type 
    AS (metric_owner int, metric_create_at int,metric_target int);

SELECT
    goal_id,
    elems.*
FROM
    table1,
    json_populate_recordset(null::metrics_type, goal_metrics) AS elems
```

Comment: Actually, if @CurtLH needs to do this regularly, then a properly normalized data model is the better choice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, this would be the most preferrable way, of course. But maybe he is not able to change the data model because of strange interfaces or something like that...

Comment: Thank you @S-Man.  This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
first un nest and give a try with ->> option

 with basejson  as (select goal_id ,goal_owner,unnest(goal_metrics) goal_metrics  from jsonmetrics ) select goal_id, goal_owner,goal_metrics->>'metric_owner' "MstricOwner",goal_metrics->>'metric_target' "MetricTGT"  from basejson;
 goal_id | goal_owner | MstricOwner | MetricTGT 
---------+------------+-------------+-----------
       4 |          1 | 143866      | 9
       2 |          2 | 143866      | 9
       2 |          2 | 143867      | 9
```